# UWP App deploy error

Tags: c#, mobile, uwp

I have two versions of one application in one project/solution with only one difference - app name. 
After installation one of them, the second app cant deploy:

```
2>Deploying to Phone Internal Storage...
2>Updating the layout...
2>Copying files: Total <1 mb to layout...
2>Checking whether required frameworks are installed...
2>Registering the application to run from layout...
2>DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147009287
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========\
```

Is there any unique data in Package.appxmanifest or Package.StoreAssociation.xml which should be changed ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to change the Package.appxmanifest for each app.

In general you need a different **Package Family Name** for each app you install.

When deploying to a phone things are slightly different. The phone uses an Id for each installed app. This is defined as the `PhoneProductId` attribute of the `PhoneIdentity` element in the Package. You need to edit the XML directly to change this. (Right click the file, select 'Open With...' and then select a suitable editor.)

If you're distributing through the store then the project will be associated with the store and so changing the name will not be sufficient to create a new store entry. You'll need a different store association for each entry in the store.